# change RootviewController to Navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

I am new to iPhone,

I want to change my `Rootviewcontroller` to my new class and make it to navigation controller.

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

I am getting `SIGABRT` says `'adding a root view controller <NewClass: 0x6a8dd50> as a child of view controller:`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whenever u want to set:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
self.window.rootViewController =nil;
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**EDIT** : Directly use `AppDelegate` `instance` to set `rootViewController` for `UIWindow` as i have shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

make `navigationController` the `rootViewController` of `window`:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Also, is `detailViewController` of type `UINavigationController`? You cannot set `UINavigationController` as root to another `UINavigationController` object.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line,

`RootViewController *defaultViewController=[[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NAME_OF_XIB" bundle:nil];`

before UINavigationController's initialization,

```
RootViewController *defaultViewController=[[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NAME_OF_XIB" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your  RootViewController to NavigationController..

```
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.detailViewController];
```